# Highcharts series label

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

From reading the highcharts docs, I can't figure out which setting turns off the series labels on the charts. How can i remove the "Result" and "Target" labels?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
series: [
{ label: { enabled: false } }
]
```